# Scheme: using open-i/o-file function

Tags: file, io, scheme, read-write, mit-scheme

I'm using MIT Scheme 10.1.5 and am curious why the following code using `open-i/o-file` is not working I expected.  Does anyone know what the issue is?

```
(define l "~/tmp0")
(define x ''(a b (c d) e f))

(let ((p (open-i/o-file l)))
  (begin (write x p)
     (flush-output p)
     (let ((r (read p)))
       (close-port p)
       r)))
;Value: #!eof
```

when I was expecting:

```
;Value: (quote (a b (c d) e f))
```

When using `open-input-file` or `open-output-file` the results are expected:

```
(let ((p (open-output-file l)))
  (write x p)
  (close-port p))

(let ((p (open-input-file l)))
  (let ((r (read p)))
    (close-port p)
    r))
;Value: (quote (a b (c d) e f))
```

Comment: You'll need to seek back to whatever the position was before you wrote.  I'm not sure if you can do that in MIT Scheme: it looks as if `open-i/o-file` is mostly fo opening device files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you read from or write to a port, the port position is advanced. After writing to an i/o port, you need to reset the position of the port if you want to read what was written.

This does not seem to be very well documented in the MIT/GNU Scheme Reference Manual, but you can use `textual-port-operation` to perform manipulations on textual ports. Now, this is a bit more convoluted than you might like for a couple of reasons.

First, `textual-port-operation` takes a port and a symbol as its arguments and returns a procedure that accomplishes the operation, i.e., `textual-port-operation` does not do the operations itself.

Second, the symbol argument to `textual-port-operation` indicates the operation, but a complete list of these symbols is not present in the reference manual (as far as I can tell). You will need to call `textual-port-operation-names` on the port to find out which operations the port supports.

Here is a rewritten version of OP code that behaves as expected:

```
(define l "./test-file.dat")
(define x ''(a b (c d) e f))

;; (define (display-port-ops p)
;;   (newline)
;;   (display (textual-port-operation-names p)) (newline)
;;   (newline))

(let* ((p (open-i/o-file l))
       (start ((textual-port-operation p 'position) p)))
  ;; (display-port-ops p)
  (write x p)
  (flush-output p)
  ((textual-port-operation p 'set-position!) p start)
  (let ((r (read p)))
    (close-port p) r))
```

Here, the `display-port-ops` procedure was used to interrogate the port and discover which operations are supported and what symbols represent those operations. This had to be called with a port argument, so it was placed in the `let*` form. I called this, uncommented, before adding either of the calls to `textual-port-operation` so that I could see which operations were available. The `position` and `set-position!` operations looked promising, so they were incorporated into the program. Note that `let*` had to replace `let` so that the value of `p` could be used in an expression calculating the `start` position.

The call to `display-port-ops`, which just wraps a call to `textual-port-operation-names`, showed this result:

```
(length pathname position set-position! truename write-self close-input eof?
 input-line input-open? input-channel buffered-output-bytes bytes-written
 close-output output-column output-open? output-channel synchronize-output
 char-set close coding known-coding? known-codings known-line-ending?
 known-line-endings line-ending open? set-coding set-line-ending
 supports-coding? char-ready? peek-char read-char read-substring unread-char
 flush-output write-char write-substring)
```

Armed with these procedures, here is what happens:

Immediately after creating the port `p`, `(textual-port-operation p 'position)` is called, yielding a procedure that will return a port position; this procedure is called on the port `p`, and `start` is bound to the result, saving the initial position of the port.

After writing to the port, `(textual-port-operation p 'set-position!)` is called, yielding a procedure that will mutate the state of a port, setting a new position; this procedure is called on the port `p` and the desired position `start`.

Now, when `read` is called on `p`, reading commences from the port's initial position.

When the program is loaded, the `test-file.dat` is created as expected, and the result of reading the file back is displayed in the REPL:

```
1 (user) => (load "file-io.scm")

;Loading "file-io.scm"... done
;Value: (quote (a b (c d) e f))
```

Comment: Well explained.  `(textual-port-operation-names p)` evaluates to a list of symbols, which I suspect are function names underneath. I'm suspecting  `(textual-port-operation p 'f)` must be something like `(lambda (p z) (if (memq z LF)) (eval z))`.

Comment: Taking a port `p` as above, both `(procedure? (textual-port-operation p 'position))` and `(procedure? (textual-port-operation p 'set-position!))` evaluate to `#t`.